# Where is Pip3 Installing Modules?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-15.10

- Ubuntu 15.10
- Python 3.4.3+
- Django 1.8.7

When I try to `import django` in the python3 interpreter, it says `ImportError: No module named 'django'`. I know Django 1.8.7 installed though, 'cause I can get the version # by doing `django-admin --version` in the terminal commandline.

When I tried `python3 manage.py runserver` in a Django project directory, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

So again (as expected), it's not in a path where Python can find it.

I looked in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages` but it's an empty directory.

I did a `whereis django` & `whereis Django` and that simply gives me a line with  `django:` or `Django:` respectively and no list of paths.

I tried Googling [how to find path to Django](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20find%20Django%20in%20Ubuntu&num=100), but that didn't turn up anything useful.

I found & checked the code of the django-admin file itself, but it doesn't have anything indicating where Django installed to. Oddly, the python file imports the django module and it works, even though the interpreter & Django project files can't see the django module. So it's on the python path but it also isn't?!? I don't know, and I can't find it.

I never had a problem like this with a previous Ubuntu (or any other OS). Has anyone got a clue how I can find where Django installed? Actually, I can't find any of the modules I installed via pip3. I've been trying to figure this out for over an hour now, and I'm very confused & frustrated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Normally pip 3 install on python3 dist-packages

You can always use pip with:

```
python3 -m pip install package
```

to check if you are experiencing troubles with another python3 installation

```
ls /usr/local/lib | grep python
```

But the easy way to not experiment this headache is by using [virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Comment: Good idea. It shows I have Python3.4 & 3.5 on the system. I had no idea that Ubuntu 15.10 had both 3.4 & 3.5 on it. So I tried starting the python interpreter as `python3.5` instead of just `python3`, and then Django worked! So, thank you! I wouldn't have guessed that Ubuntu was putting on 2 versions of Python 3 & then having the default one be the older version while `pip3` installs to the newer version by default. They hadn't done that before.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have installed django outside virtual environment. 
 download virtual environment by

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv your_env
```

Activate virtual environment.

```
source your_env/bin/activate
```

Then, 
Install django in your virtual environment.

Comment: This works, thanks. I didn't want to use virtualenv though, I want this to be system wide.

Comment: Virtual environments add some slight mental and process overhead in comparison to globally accessible installation, but provide the most flexibility.