# Where exactly is pip installed?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, pip

I know the newer versions of python come with pip installed. So 'sudo apt-get install python3-pip' gives me that it is installed saying that it is the latest version, then why does 'pip install django' gives an error saying pip is not insatlled? Namely this:

The program 'pip' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install python-pip

I again run 'sudo apt-get install python-pip' (for python 2.7) which installs version 1.5. So i try pip install -U pip and it downloads the package marked 7.1 and succesfully installs. However on checking the version again it is still 1.5

Comment: you seem to be mixing python versions, you start out looking at pip for python 3, but to use pip for python 3 i believe you need to use `pip3 install django`

Comment: This is almost an exact duplicate of a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34864038/1324033) I answered yesterday, the answer is the same at least

Comment: if virtualenv the make sure running correct Virtualenv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is Pip3 Installing Modules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906336/where-is-pip3-installing-modules)

Answer (score 0):

You can install pip with the help of get-pip.py script.
you can download this script and execute on your terminal "python get-pip.py".
it will install pip on your system.
you can also use curl to download get-pip.py script-
curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py".

To verify the installation you can use-
pip --help
pip -V